# find in array of mongoose subdoc to return array of documents with similar fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

these are my schemas and the
queries are: (list's id and a question topic)
questionSchema is nested inside the listSchema.

```
const questionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    topic: { type : String , unique : false , required : true },
    name: { type : String , unique : true, required : true }
})

const listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    listName: { type : String , unique : true, required : true },
    questionSet: { type : [questionSchema] , unique : true }
})
```

What i want to do is to find a list in this list schema with id and then i want to find all the questions with similar topic from that list and then i want to pass all the array result (all questions with same topic) to my ejs file.

do i have to nest multiple finds inside each other or there is some other method?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate out the schemas and use `populate` from mongoose to do the job. It has a very powerful API.

Here's more information: [Link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

Comment: man i also wish if i could do so but the project is 70% completed and i have to make too many changes for it. thanks for the help i'll learn more about this api hopefully it will help me in future